# react loadable undefined json key

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-loadable

Im trying to use react loadable with server side rendering.

My babel plugins config

```
 "plugins": [
      "syntax-dynamic-import",
      "dynamic-import-node",
      "react-loadable/babel",
      [
        "import-inspector",
        {
          "serverSideRequirePath": true,
          "webpackRequireWeakId": true
        }
      ],
      "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
      "transform-react-inline-elements",
      "transform-react-constant-elements"
    ]
```

server response during rendering, with:

```
  console.log(modules);
  const bundles = getBundles(stats, modules);
  console.log(bundles);
```

gets:

```
[ 'HomePage' ]
[ undefined ]
```

i guess my error comes from `react-loadable.json` which has one of the keys `undefined`

```
  "undefined": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "./node_modules/react-intl/lib/index.es.js",
      "file": "main.a77d1cb1913eab1806a7.js"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "./node_modules/redux/es/index.js",
      "file": "main.a77d1cb1913eab1806a7.js"
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "name": "./node_modules/redux-saga/es/internal/sagaHelpers/index.js",
      "file": "main.a77d1cb1913eab1806a7.js"
    }
  ]
```

but i can figure out how it becomes undefined if i have `webpackChunkName` and modules defined like this:

```
export default Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "HomePage" */ './index'),
  loading: () => null,
  modules: ['HomePage'],
});
```

maybe someone had similar problem or know any solution?

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this @ewief?

Comment: i managed to solve it.
Now its all working because react-loadable fixed compatibility issues with webpack4 @Thomas

Comment: @ewief Can you share what was your fix? I have similar problem

Comment: @fiddlest instead of using relative path for import: import('./index') i used absolute path import('containers/HomePage') and it fixed the issue. As react-loadable is basically not supported now i moved to loadable-components.

Comment: @ewief I am using webpack alias for path. Are you using it to ? react-loadable is abandoned ?

Comment: @fiddlest im using `resolve.modules`. react-loadable doesnt accept any issues and is no longer recommended in docs by react team also last update was `7 months ago`

Comment: Thanks @ewief I should move to loadable-components as well.
Its a lot of work to change ..